# How to open an activity with a push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm working in a example of application which receives push notifications.

Everything works well, I execute a python script and I receive the push notification.

The problem appears when I push into the notification. I can't make the notification open the app...

Project's structure is:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sergi.pruebapush;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationService.class);
    startService(i);
}
}
```

**NotificationsListenerService.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class NotificationsListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
}
```

**RegistrationService.java**

```
package com.example.sergi.pruebapush;

import android.app.IntentService; import android.content.Intent; 
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub; 
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging; 
 import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;


public class RegistrationService extends IntentService {
public RegistrationService() {
    super("RegistrationService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    InstanceID myID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    String registrationToken="";
    try {
        registrationToken = myID.getToken(
            getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,
                    null
                        );
        Log.d("Registration Token", registrationToken);
        GcmPubSub subscription = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        subscription.subscribe(registrationToken, "/topics/my_little_topic", null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} }
```

**TokenRefreshListenerService.java**

```
package com.example.sergi.pruebapush;

import android.content.Intent;

import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;


 public class TokenRefreshListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService    
 {
  @Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationService.class);
    startService(i);
}
}
```

**send.py**

```
from urllib2 import *
import urllib
import json
import sys
MY_API_KEY="************************************************"
 messageTitle = sys.argv[1]
messageBody = sys.argv[2]
data={
"to" : "/topics/my_little_topic",
"notification" : {
    "body" : messageBody,
    "title" : messageTitle,
    "icon" : "ic_launcher"
}
}
dataAsJSON = json.dumps(data)
request = Request(
"https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
dataAsJSON,
{ "Authorization" : "key="+MY_API_KEY,
"Content-type" : "application/json"
}
 )
print urlopen(request).read()
```

What can I add to my example to open the app pushing the notification?

Comment: Check this http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/

Comment: i will check it, thanks! but i still ned an example to complete this code :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're sending a notification which can't be used to launch the app, you have to use data payload, then implment onMessageRecieved and sendNotification.

[GcmListenerService Example from google](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java)

Example includes onMessageReceived, called when push notification received from server, which will call sendNotification.
sendNotification implements, pending intent. Which will start MainActivity.

Edit:

[Notification payload support](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

Or you can add click into notification

send.py

```
data={
"to" : "/topics/my_little_topic",
"notification" : {
    "body" : messageBody,
    "title" : messageTitle,
    "icon" : "ic_launcher"
    "click_action" : "com.example.test"
}
}
```

Add intent filter to activity you want to start

manifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.test" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Please explain the relevant details in your answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer